# Filter out branches in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I would like to filter some data in elastic search 2.4. 
More specifically, I would like to only consider the records that are under the 'island' label.
If I filter like this :

```
filter : [{term: {Artists.Artist.Records.label : "Island"}}]
```

I would lose Miles, but keep the two others because they have an island label. That's good, but I would like to lose *all none island records*, but still keep all data from the top.

So given :

```
{
  "Artists": [
    {
      "Artist": "Tom Waits",
      "Records": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "Rain dogs",
          "label": "Island"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "SwordFishTrombones",
          "label": "Island"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "title": "Bone Machine",
          "label": "ANTI"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Artist": "dEUS",
      "Records": [
        {
          "id": 112,
          "title": "Worst Case Scenario",
          "label": "Island"
        },
        {
          "id": 2213,
          "title": "Keep you close",
          "label": "Universal"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Artist": "Miles",
      "Records": [
        {
          "id": 42,
          "title": "Kind of blue",
          "label": "columbia"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to end up with :

```
{
  "Artists": [
    {
      "Artist": "Tom Waits",
      "Records": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "Rain dogs",
          "label": "Island"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "SwordFishTrombones",
          "label": "Island"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Artist": "dEUS",
      "Records": [
        {
          "id": 112,
          "title": "Worst Case Scenario",
          "label": "Island"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is that possible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this can be accomplished with inner hits functionality. Your query would look something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {"match_all": {}},
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "Artists.Artist.Records",
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "Records.label": "Island"
            }
          }, 
          "inner_hits" : {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```